# Knockout js - validate if value is not empty or different to 0 to display text in data-bind

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have 2 attributes **precio_anterior** and **precio_suscriptor**, and i do not know how validate with data-binding if **precio_anterior** is not empty or different to 0 to display **precio_anterior** text, but if it is the opposite display **precio_suscriptor** text, this is my code:

```
<div class="prices-box">
                <span class="qty"><span data-bind="text: qty"></span> x
                    <span class="subscribe-price" data-bind="precio_anterior != '' && precio_anterior != 0 ? text: precio_anterior : text:precio_suscriptor"></span>
                </span>
                <span data-bind="html: fascicle"></span>                
            </div>
```

I know this is not right, but i need this with knockout js.

**Edit:**

I added the $ sign to the variable **precio_anterior** and returns $0 when variable is empty in the backend

```
<div class="prices-box">
                <span class="qty"><span data-bind="text: qty"></span> x
                    <span class="subscribe-price" data-bind="precio_anterior != '' || precio_anterior != $0 ? text: precio_anterior : text:precio_suscriptor"></span>
                </span>
                <span data-bind="html: fascicle"></span>                
            </div>
```

Any help, is it possible with script and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ternary goes like this: `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`.

Not empty and not 0 will evaluate to `true`, so in this case you could use the logical OR operator:

`<span class="subscribe-price" data-bind="text: precio_anterior() || precio_suscriptor()"></span>`

This will show `precio_anterior` if it evaluates to `true` (so not empty and > 0), and `precio_suscriptor` otherwise. You didn't specify if these variables are observables; if they're not, then remove the `()`.

Comment: I try `<span class="subscribe-price" data-bind="text: precio_anterior || precio_suscriptor"></span>` but always get the value of `precio_anterior` so the value of `precio_anterior` is 0, when i need `precio_suscriptor` in this case

Comment: My bad, I added the $ sign to the variable, `precio_anterior` returns $0 when is empty in the backend, edit the question, thanks @Brother Woodrow

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a condition, Thank you @Brother Woodrow your answer was a guide for add a correct condition:

This is my solve code:

```
<div class="prices-box">
                <span class="qty"><span data-bind="text: qty"></span> x
                    <!-- ko if: precio_anterior == "" || precio_anterior == "$0" -->
                    <span class="subscribe-price" data-bind="text: precio_suscriptor"></span>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: precio_anterior !== "" && precio_anterior !== "$0" -->
                    <span class="before-price" data-bind="text: precio_anterior"></span><span class="info">Precio Antes</span>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </span>
                <span data-bind="html: fascicle"></span>                
            </div>
```

Thanks!